# Protractor get elements by repeater

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angularjs-ng-repeat

I see this in my HTML after it is generated, in the browser:

```
<!-- ngRepeat: (promptId, q) in questions -->
```

I want to get the first element, so I use:

```
  it('add new comment thread', function () {
    element.all(by.repeater('(promptId, q) in questions')).first().click();
  });
```

But I get an error:

> Failed: Index out of bound. Trying to access element at index: 0, but
>   there are only 0 elements that match locator by.repeater("(promptId,
>   q) in questions")

There is clearly at least one child element here, so am I using by.repeater incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is, generally speaking, difficult to answer questions like this without seeing what is actually happening in your particular test for your particular application.

First of all, note that *this comment would be there even if no repeater elements are present*.

---

This can be a "timing problem", *waiting for presence of an element helps*:

```
var prompt = element.all(by.repeater('(promptId, q) in questions')).first();
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(prompt), 5000);
prompt.click();

// TODO: your expectation here
```

And, of course, make sure you are on the expected page when you try to click the element and the repeater is actually contains/fed with data.